# Sort function in Java collections

Tags: java, android

If I have following list of student objects,

```
obj1.Name = "ABC";
obj1.Rank = 5;

obj2.Name = "DEF",
obj2.Rank = 3;

obj3.Name = "GHI";
obj3.Rank = 2;

obj4.Name = "JKL";
obj4.Rank = 0;

obj5.Name = "MNO";
obj5.Rank = 1;

obj6.Name = "PQR";
obj6.Rank = 4;
```

I need to sort these objects in following order.

```
obj5,
obj3,
obj2,
obj6,
obj1,
obj4.
```

I have tried following code,

```
Collections.sort(studentList, new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student obj2, Student obj1) {
            return obj2.Rank.compareTo(obj1.Rank);
    }
});
```

I am getting following result.

```
obj4,//this should be in last position
obj5,
obj3,
obj2,
obj6,
obj1.
```

But I need all zero's should be at last.

Comment: Why don't you set Rank of obj4 to "6"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to sort them with 0 higher than any value is:

```
Collections.sort(StudentList, new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student obj1, Student obj2) {
        if(obj1.Rank==0) return (obj2.Rank==0) ? 0 : 1;
        if(obj2.Rank==0) return -1;
        return Integer.compare(obj1.Rank,obj2.Rank);
    }
});
```

This will correctly handle the case where `obj.Rank=Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

If your `Rank`s are Integers rather than `int`s you'll also need to handle the case where they're `null`.

Comment: Thank you for concern `Integer.MAX_VALUE` . +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put 0's last in sort order, and leave others in ascending order (ie: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0), you'll need to write a custom `Comparator` that treats 0's as the largest value.  Possibly something like this:

```
Collections.sort(StudentList, new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student obj1, Student obj2) {
        Integer compareRank1 = obj1.Rank == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : obj1.Rank;
        Integer compareRank2 = obj2.Rank == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : obj2.Rank;
        return compareRank1.compareTo(compareRank2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course this is going to fail if you actually have a value with rank `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit compare method , and put a check for zero

```
Collections.sort(studentList, new Comparator<Student>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student obj2, Student obj1) {
    if(obj1.rank ==0 ){
         if(obj2.rank ==0){
          // when both count are zero then you can handle here
         }
        // return positive int beacuse zero is greater than everyother count
      }
    else return obj2.Rank.compareTo(obj1.Rank);
    }
});
```